# How to change the style of display in python dataframe from column to column?

Tags: python, dataframe

In order to change the style of display in python dataframe, we can write the following command to change it to have eight decimal places.
`pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.8f}'.format`

However, if we want to have different styles in different columns (e.g., no decimal place in some columns and 8 decimal places in some columns), how can we achieve this outcome by index?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check pandas documentation in here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html. Hope it helps

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try? Any research?